Range of $f(x)=\arccos(x)+\arctan(x)$
How to prove that the range of $f$ is $\left[\tfrac{\pi}{4},\tfrac{3\pi}{4}\right]$ without using derivatives:
$$
f(x)=\arccos(x)+\arctan(x),\;x\in[-1,1]
$$
Approach:
$$
f(x)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)+\arctan(x)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right),\;x\in]0,1[
$$
Note that: $f(x)=\pi-f(-x)$, $-1\le x\le1$
Any hint would be appreciated.

Have you checked $f(\pm1)$?

Let $\alpha=\arccos (x),\beta=\arctan (x)$. Then $\cos \alpha=\tan \beta$,so $\alpha\in [0,\pi],\beta\in [-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$. We only need to show $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \alpha+\beta\leq \frac{3}{4}\pi$.
For the left inequality, if $\alpha\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$, then it obviously holds. Now assume $\alpha\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. By monotoncity of $\tan$, it is equivalent to show $\tan \beta\geq \tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha)$, which is equivalent to $\cos \alpha\geq \tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\alpha)$. After removing the bracket, this is equivalent to $\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha+\tan\alpha\geq 1$, which is trivial since $\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha\geq 1$ when $\alpha\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.
For the right inequality, the proof is similar. (Consider the cases where $\alpha\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\alpha\geq\frac{\pi}{2}$).
Finally, note that $x=\pm1$ gives the equalities.

Continuing your idea:
let's rationalize the inside expression by multiplying by $1+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on both numerator and denominator.
$\begin{align}\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+x}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}&=\dfrac{\Big(x^2+\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)\Big(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)}{x\Big(1-(1-x^2)\Big)}\\\\&=\dfrac{x^2+(1-x^2)+(x+1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^3}\\\\&=\dfrac{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^3}\end{align}$

Now in $0$ the numerator is $2$ while the denominator is $0$ therefore the function goes to $\pm\infty$

Notice also that on $[-1,1]$ the numerator is $\ge 1$ (since both $x+1$ and the square root are $\ge 0$) while $|x^3|\le 1$, therefore their ratio is $\ge 1$ in absolute value.



In conclusion this ratio range is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,+\infty)$ and the $\arctan$ of this gives you the desired result.

